# This CAPTCHA looks vulnerable, does this other CAPTCHA have the same vulnerability and how do I crack it?

Tags: python, html, string, captcha, decode

I am working on a lab  (a purposely vulnerable website, on a sandboxed VM) for one of my cyber security courses. The goal of the lab is to bypass a captcha.

I've have a script that pulls out the VIEWSTATE, EVENTVLIDATION, and CaptchaId from a HTML Site. I am trying to figure out how I decode the Captcha ID. Here is the line I am scraping

```
<div id="CaptchaImage"><img src="Captcha.ashx?CaptchaId=1d7a4981-ad6b-429e-aefc-011b691b6db0" />
```

The captcha value for this encoding is tzfifq

My script gives me a value of 1d7a4981-ad6b-429e-aefc-011b691b6db0

Here is my script:

```
import requests
import urlparse
import lxml.html
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print "Enter the URL"
url = raw_input()
print url

# Parse Site
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

#Finding Captcha
captcha = soup.findAll("input", {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "CaptchaId"})
print captcha[0]['value']

#Finding ViewState
viewstate = soup.findAll("input", {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "__VIEWSTATE"})
print viewstate[0]['value']

#Finding eventvalidation
eventval = soup.findAll("input", {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "__EVENTVALIDATION"})
print eventval[0]['value']
```

Here's the HTML. It's a screenshot because this is running in a virtual machine without clipboard access.

[image: source]
[bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH0Jt.png)

And for context, here's another "CAPTCHA" that led me to ask the question:

[image: source]
[bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6JHb.png)

Thanks in advance.
-Phil

Comment: If it's just a half-decent captcha implementation, you won't be able to solve it without doing some advanced OCR - that ID you pulled out is just a GUID, the captcha value can't be determined from that.

Comment: +1 because it's an interesting question (not necessarily a good one)

Comment: @Joe How could it be a better question? I'm new to this site. I researched as much as I could. Read several sites but they kept referring to OCR which our professor specifically said we will not need to use to solve this lab?

Comment: The premise of the question means that you misunderstand how CAPTCHAs work, but didn't research how they work, hence someone downvoted you. I think it's interesting because it's a natural question to have when learning about CAPTCHAs, hence I upvoted.

Comment: I understand how captchas work, the thing is I thought and maybe this is ignorance on my part, that this was simply encoded in keeping with the other three captchas in my lab. Because of this I thought to myself that the captcha was simply encoded or encrypted and could be broken with the original captcha text. 

I did this on my other 3 labs and it worked, I think that's where the confusion came from.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'lab', but it's possible that people have implemented a CATPCHA this way. It's not a standard way of doing it. If the value were encoded then it should be done with a secret key, so if the cryptography was any good you would still have to treat it as a randomly generaetd number.

Comment: @Joe What I mean by lab is that it is a sandboxed site that is purposely vulnerable. That's why I have to connect to it via a vm.

Comment: Aha. If I were you I would re-write your question to say something like "this CAPTCHA looks vulnerable, does this other CAPTCHA have the same vulnerability and how do I crack it?". (The answer will still be the same!) The Python code you included isn't really relevant.

Comment: Have you looked for ways to bypass the CAPTCHA entirely? Say, by determining that upon success, the page sets a "CAPTCHA_passed" cookie, and setting it manually. Also, I'd check the values of __VIEWSTATE / __EVENTVALIDATION, and see if you can just send in the POST data with a known CAPTCHA/ID combination.

Comment: @user3757614 Can you expand on your last sentence? The ViewState and Event are randomly generated so how would I find a CAPTCHA ID combo?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head what purpose __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION serve, but they look like base64 encoding, so I'd want to turn them readable, to check for anything useful. In any case, that's more of a hail mary than anything useful. Personally, I would just manually decode a single CAPTCHA, and force the ID to the known value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CAPTCHA is worth its salt, the ID will be a [surrogate ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Treat it as a randomly generated number. The point of the CAPTCHA is that the link between these two things is secret (known only on the server), but can be decoded by a human. If a machine could do it just be reverse engineering the ID, it wouldn't be a CAPTCHA.

Looking at the format, this looks like a [Microsoft GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a combination of randomly generated numbers. It's not an encoded value, so there's nothing to decode.

Machine vision (OCR) is difficult to do, but there are projects dedicated to cracking CAPTCHAS using it. If it were as easy as reverse-engineering an ID, then people wouldn't bother with machine vision.

Comment: What's throwing me for a loop is the same ID is present in the CaptchaId value field as well as the img src. You are able to bypass the captcha in all of the labs, so I know somehow it can be done without using an OCR.

The other three labs I did had the captcha in plain text or BASE64. Unfortunately I don't have enough Rep to post an image or I would show you the HTML source.

Comment: You can copy-paste the HTML source into the question if it's relevant.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be a screenshot as the source is on a VM that doesn't have the capability to transfer text.

Comment: The fact that the ID is present in more than one element isn't surprising. The server will choose a value to send you in HTML. The document will then fetch the image based on its ID. You type it in an submit the form. The server will know what fields were sent back by the form, so it can match the field up with the value stored.

Comment: Upload it to imgur and add the URL as a comment. I'll edit your question.

Comment: Question edited. I presume you're asking about the hidden field. That's not surprising. It's just telling the server which CAPTCHA to compare the typed-in value with.

Comment: To give you an idea, and to add context to the question. Here is one with the captcha in clear text. Yes, I know this is VERY rare in the real-world.

http://imgur.com/biFpF6Z

Comment: That's interesting. Where did you find that? That's something designed to look like a CAPTCHA but ... really isn't. I wouldn't trust that software.

Comment: It's a cyber security lab.

Comment: If it's how it looks, and that's public facing, I would have serious words with the person who implemented that.